# Using DrawImage in winform

Tags: c++, winforms, graphics

I am trying to use DrawImage in winform, which draws the specified portion of the specified Image at the specified location and with the specified size. But I am getting certain errors.

```
  error C2039: 'Graphics' : is not a member of 'System::EventArgs'   
  error C2227: left of '->DrawImage' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

The following code snippet taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142038.aspx), performs the following:

1- Creates an image from a JPEG file SampImag.jpg in the folder of the example.

2- Creates points that define a parallelogram in which to draw the image.

3- Creates a rectangle to select the portion of the image to draw.

4- Sets the graphics drawing unit to pixel.

5- Draws the image to the screen.

To use this code snippet in my application, I created a simple winform application.  In the form I added a button.    On button click I want that the following code to execute:

```
private:
  void DrawImageParaRect( PaintEventArgs^ e )
  {

  // Create image.
  Image^ newImage = Image::FromFile( "SampImag.jpg" );

  // Create parallelogram for drawing image.
  Point ulCorner = Point(100,100);
  Point urCorner = Point(325,100);
  Point llCorner = Point(150,250);
  array<Point>^ destPara = {ulCorner,urCorner,llCorner};

  // Create rectangle for source image.
  Rectangle srcRect = Rectangle(50,50,150,150);
  GraphicsUnit units = GraphicsUnit::Pixel;

  // Draw image to screen.
  e->Graphics->DrawImage( newImage, destPara, srcRect, units );
  }
```

In the application that I created, I got the following lines for the button:

```
  #pragma endregion
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)      
 {


  }
```

So I am putting the code inside this event, as shown below:

```
 #pragma endregion
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)      
 {   


  // Create image.
  Image^ newImage = Image::FromFile( "SampImag.jpg" );

  // Create parallelogram for drawing image.
  Point ulCorner = Point(100,100);
  Point urCorner = Point(325,100);
  Point llCorner = Point(150,250);
  array<Point>^ destPara = {ulCorner,urCorner,llCorner};

  // Create rectangle for source image.
  Rectangle srcRect = Rectangle(50,50,150,150);
  GraphicsUnit units = GraphicsUnit::Pixel;

  // Draw image to screen.
  e->Graphics->DrawImage( newImage, destPara, srcRect, units );
  }
```

How do I get rid of the error?

```
   error C2039: 'Graphics' : is not a member of 'System::EventArgs'  
   error C2227: left of '->DrawImage' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

I have put  system.drawing.dll in the folder where my form1.h is present.

Following is the complete code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#using <system.drawing.dll>




using namespace System;
 using namespace System::Drawing;


 #pragma once

 namespace Zooming_10Nov {


    using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for Form1
/// </summary>
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~Form1()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
protected: 

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(120, 91);
        this->button1->Name = L"button1";
        this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->button1->Text = L"button1";
        this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(292, 273);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
        this->Name = L"Form1";
        this->Text = L"Form1";
        this->ResumeLayout(false);

    }
 #pragma endregion
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)  
{






  // Create image.
  Image^ newImage = Image::FromFile( "SampImag.jpg" );

  // Create parallelogram for drawing image.
  Point ulCorner = Point(100,100);
  Point urCorner = Point(325,100);
  Point llCorner = Point(150,250);
  array<Point>^ destPara = {ulCorner,urCorner,llCorner};

  // Create rectangle for source image.
  Rectangle srcRect = Rectangle(50,50,150,150);
  GraphicsUnit units = GraphicsUnit::Pixel;

  // Draw image to screen.
  e->Graphics->DrawImage( newImage, destPara, srcRect, units );




         }
};
 }
```

Comment: This is fundamentally the wrong way to accomplish this.  There are many excellent books about Winforms programming.  Pick one up from your local library to avoid the trial and error.

Comment: I am debuging a code of 100000 lines, written by somebody else, where I have to put a small feature of zooming, and I have no plans to do winform applications in near future. So how will it justify my time to read books. Those who are experts in area can point me relevant articles. That will be helpful also. Thanks in advance for your valuable time..

Answer (score 1):

Like the compiler said: '**Graphics**': is not a member of '**System::EventArgs**'.
The only Event Arguments that have a Graphics object is the PaintEventArgs, which you will only get on Paint and PaintBackground.

Now, since you want to draw the image on the button click event, you will have to create the graphics object for the surface area on which you want to draw the image.

Based on the provided code I'm guessing that you want to draw the image directly to the form. You can create the graphics object by the forms handle, like this:

```
Graphics^ graphicsInstance = Graphics::FromHwnd(this->Handle);
```

and simply replace `e->Graphics` with `graphicsInstance` to get this call:

```
graphicsInstance->DrawImage( newImage, destPara, srcRect, units );
```

*More details on the painting itself:*
As you could see in the article that you have provided, they have just posted the method and conveniently passed the **PaintEventArgs** as an argument, this is a typical pattern used when overriding the **OnPaint** and **OnPaintBackground** to reduce clutter in the paint event code. So just make sure to pass the graphics object from either of the two paint events to your helper method, or if necessary create you own with the method above (Explore the Graphics type a little bit, you will see that you can create it from multiple sources, not just the form's handle).
You can find a nice article on code project with some Theory Crafting around drawing in WinFroms here: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1355/Professional-C-Graphics-with-GDI)